# MySQL to PostgreSQL convert issue - pgloader on WSL

Tags: migration, pgloader

I'm trying to convert MySQL 5.6 to PostgreSQL 14 via WSL pgloader with below command.

```
pgloader mysql://root:password@172.18.160.1/dbname1 postgresql://postgres:root@172.18.160.1/dbname1
```

But it's showing below error, Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
2022-05-17T09:16:03.014000Z LOG pgloader version "3.6.1"
2022-05-17T09:16:03.016000Z LOG Data errors in '/tmp/pgloader/'
2022-05-17T09:16:03.122000Z LOG Migrating from #<MYSQL-CONNECTION mysql://root@172.18.160.1:3306/dbname1{1005D97DD3}>
2022-05-17T09:16:03.122000Z LOG Migrating into #<PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://postgres@172.18.160.1:5432/dbname1{1005FB32F3}>
KABOOM!
INFO: Control stack guard page unprotected
Control stack guard page temporarily disabled: proceed with caution

What I am doing here?

Control stack exhausted (no more space for function call frames).
This is probably due to heavily nested or infinitely recursive function
calls, or a tail call that SBCL cannot or has not optimized away.

PROCEED WITH CAUTION.
```

I have tried several methods from Google to convert to PostgreSQL, but it's not working.

Please let me know if there is any best alternative way to convert MySQL to PostgreSQL. I have a big size of database, so looking for the best way for migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by reinstalling the WSL2 with ubuntu 20.4 it's working perfectly now.

Thank you!